# How to integrate WordPress with Angular 8 for website?

Tags: php, angular, wordpress, rest, content-management-system

I am trying to create a single page website using the following technologies,
 - Angular version 8+
 - WordPress

I could n't find many resources to work on WordPress with Angular 8+. Most of the resources/solutions available are for React or AngularJS.

What I have found so far only shows how to fetch data from WordPress website using get method inside service with */wp-json/wp/v2/posts/* endpoint. However, what I am looking is to create the website from scratch.

Any guideline or ideas regarding this would be very helpful. 
I have got a lot of question about it.

- If I set up local Angular environment, How I am gonna use it on WordPress.

Comment: react or AngularJS, it would be same idea for Angular version 8+..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it all manual in code and also, you can find some sort of plugin to assist in this manner. I have utilized both methods in my coding career.

Have a look on **WP-NG** is a plugin to automatic bootstrap angular application. Activate module by admin page and use directly directive. I have used this in 2-3 projects. Let, me say it clearly depends on your requirement, what you want to achieve.

[Angular for WordPress - Free WP Plugin Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ng/)

In case, you are still preferring code for broader aspect. Try something like this.

**1) Setup WordPress and a new theme
2) Enqueue scripts in the theme
3) Setup the theme
4) Create the AngularJS application**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

// set the configuration
myapp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  // the following data is fetched from the JavaScript variables created by wp_localize_script(), and stored in the Angular rootScope
  $rootScope.dir = BlogInfo.url;
  $rootScope.site = BlogInfo.site;
  $rootScope.api = AppAPI.url;
}]);

// add a controller
myapp.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  // load posts from the WordPress API
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $scope.api, // derived from the rootScope
    params: {
      json: 'get_posts'
    }
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.postdata = data.posts;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  });
}]);
```

Also, you can give a look on this blog, I found it on Quora some days back, its good to read. Yeah its for Angular 6 but can help in many ways. [Angular 6 blog on WordPress RestAPIs](http://guruquest.net/blog/)

Comment: Do I understand this in the right manner? If I create my own plugin and use the WP-NG plugin inside, do I and later my customer also have to install the two plugins?

Comment: I don' think its a reliable option. This angular code is from Angular JS and also the plugin you mentioned is not compatible with the last 3 major WP versions.

Comment: The question is about Angular 8, your answer is for AngularJS (which is version 1, after which they dropped the JS suffix).